# SQL error: "Incorrect syntax near AND"

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, sql-server-2005

```
"[..] security info=False;initial catalog=pooja2011"

Dim cmd As New Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand
Dim con As New Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection(constr)

Try
   Dim strSql As String = "UPDATE a1_ticket SET BANK = '" & Literal20.Text & "' AND PAID = '" & Label1.Text & "'AND BID = '" & Literal21.Text & "' WHERE Ticket_no ='" & Literal3.Text & "'"

   '------------"
   con.Open()
   cmd.Connection = con
   cmd.CommandText = strSql
   cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
Catch ex As Exception
   Response.Write(ex.Message)
Finally
   cmd.Dispose()
   con.Dispose()
End Try
```

***ERROR : Incorrect syntax near AND***

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are not using parametrized queries and thus making your code vulnerable to SQL injection. Here's how to improve it:

```
Try
    Using conn = New SqlConnection(constr)
    Using cmd = conn.CreateCommand()
        conn.Open()
        Dim sql As String = "UPDATE a1_ticket SET BANK = @bank, PAID = @paid, BID = @bid WHERE Ticket_no = @ticketNo"
        cmd.CommandText = sql
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@bank", Literal20.Text)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@paid", Label1.Text)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@bid", Literal21.Text)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ticketNo", Literal3.Text)
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
    End Using
    End Using
Catch ex As Exception
    Response.Write(ex.Message)
End Try
```

Comment: I never liked application embedded SQL anyways =)

Comment: @bitxwise, I think that there is nothing wrong with embedding SQL in the application. You just need to do it in the proper layer (which in this case is very wrong because it is in the web UI layer) and you should also do it properly. If those two conditions are satisfied it is OK for me.

Comment: @Darin: Perhaps from an architecture POV, sure, but from other POV's I still would avoid it (i.e. maintenance, DBA woes, just to name a couple hehe)

Comment: @user594849, I've updated my answer. Use `,` instead of `AND` to specify multiple fields to be updated.

Answer (score 0):

Well, the AND doesn't have a space after the single quote:

```
Label1.Text & "'AND BID = '"
```

should probably be:

```
Label1.Text & "' AND BID = '"
```

If this doesn't resolve your issue, can you post your error message?